# Dilatation invariance of Borel sets in $\mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $A$ a Borel set in $\mathbb{R^n}$ and $\alpha > 0$. Is it true to say that:

$$
\alpha A = A,
$$

Thanks,

S

Answer (score 2):

Of course not. (When $n=1$)  $2(1,2)=(2,4) \neq (1,2)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.